# ELKI tool - outlier detection results for ABOD

Tags: data-mining, outliers, elki

I am trying to run ELKI for Outlier Detection using ABOD method. I see the various visualizations as result, but not the outlier scores or rankings. What should I do to say get top 10 outliers using ELKI?

Comment: I ran the algorithm using MiniGui. For changing the Result format/ getting outlier ranking, I do not know which parameter etc to change! Is there a good page on the tutorial for the MiniGui - understanding and using various parameters?

Comment: Don't use it, but have you seen this? http://www.dragonwake.com/download/minigui-1.6.10/docs/MINIGUI-PROG-GUIDE-V2.0-4E.pdf Looks long enough to at least stand a chance of providing the answer.

Comment: @AleksanderLidtke that link has nothing to do with ELKI minigui.

Comment: @user3065574 Look at the output file. It should be sorted, outliers first. Note that with ABOD, low scores are outliers.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your suggestions - tried loading the results to a file/score-dumper - It gives this error - Could not evaluate outlier results, as I could not find a minority label - Any help?

Comment: Things worked...thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

The ELKI `ResultWriter` will write the outliers to a file **in decreasing outlierness** (if the method is implemented with the appropriate metadata to allow correct sorting).

As for ABOD, please not that the implementation you are using (ELKI 0.6.0~beta2 and before) is actually **FastABOD**, unless you set `abod.k` to the data set size. The 0.6.0 release will have separate classes for ABOD, FastABOD and LB-ABOD. But since ABOD scales `O(n^3)` it will be only usable for small data sets!

Comment: What does abod.samplesize stand for? I am confused that to run fast abod whether I should be using the parameter abod.k or abod.samplesize?

Comment: Are you using ELKI 0.6.0?

Answer (score 0):

You can see the result if you use the cmd (command line) for running the algorithm like this

```
java -cp <<path>> -algorithm outlier.ABOD -dbc.in data.txt -out myresults/ABOD
```

, on `<<path>>` that containd `elki.jar/elki.jar de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.application.KDDCLIApplication`